# Outlook 2013 Functions - Combinate Date() + "String Literal" in outlook template using Developer Tools

Tags: outlook, ms-office

With the developer tools enabled and after clicking "Design this Form" I am able to

right click the subject line-->Properties-->Value-->"Set the initial value of this field to:"

and I enter Date() + "text" and many other variations but nothing will display properly. I simply want the date displayed in addition to other strings. I also set it to calculate every time the message/template is opened

Answer (score 0):

The format of your function is invalid; use Date() & "text".

Comment: thanks. where is documentation that would have answered my question?